# Spring + react deploy

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, webpack

I am trying to use spring tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/
to run my spring + react application.

In the tutorial he does everything on one page but my application is using Router component to switch between pages so it doesn't work with spring controller serving one address.

What can I do to make it work? I tried googling for it and read many stack overflow questions but couldn't find answer to my problem.

Comment: Yes, You'll need custom Route handling on React Application to handle the routes. While, Spring will need to be configured to serve the same application(html and js) files for all the routes

Comment: But how do I do it? Do you have any example?

Comment: For what, the spring part or react part ?

Comment: For both I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

I had to paste address of server I want to deploy to as a proxy setting for react project, execute `npm run build` in react project root directory, copy files from build directory into resources/static directory in spring boot project and then I deployed project to heroku as described in this guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java.